# how to get Tools/Options settings value

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm try to get some options settings value like `Nuget Package Manager\Package Source`

[image]

I tried `ShellSettingsManager`, it return a GUID value:

```cs
var manager = new ShellSettingsManager(ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider);
var store = manager.GetReadOnlySettingsStore(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.SettingsScope.Configuration);
var package = store.GetString(@"\ToolsOptionsPages\NuGet Package Manager\Package Sources\", "Package"); // get a GUID
```

Comment: As far as l know, the nuget package sources are  stored  in the nuget.config file(`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`). And I think you can get the contents of the node packageSources in this XML file in code. You can refer to this document for getting the nodes in the XML. Hope it could help you.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT thanks a lot, I found the visualstudio nuget api, see the answer below :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the nuget api can be use.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/nuget-api-in-visual-studio#ivspackagesourceprovider-interface

```cs
var componentModel = (IComponentModel)await GetServiceAsync(typeof(SComponentModel));
var sourceProvider = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageSourceProvider>();
var sources = sourceProvider.GetSources(true, true);
```